# Integrate Online Dynamics CRM with On Premise Exchange. Is that possible

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

we have an in-house exchange server and we would like to integrate that with our Online Dynamics CRM application at /CompanyName/.crm.dynamics.com

We do not have any online exchange account with Microsoft yet and do not plan to add that. I went to server profiles interface within the Email Settings and tried adding both exchange and POP3-SMTP. But nothing helped. Way the settings are, I don' think Microsoft even allows setting up on premise exchange server with Online Dynamics CRM.

Is that so or am I doing something wrong

Any clue where should I start.

Comment: Your tags don't make sense, CRM online is latest version i.e. 2015, how can you use CRM 2011 here?

Comment: @James:Tag Removed , Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM Online only supports Exchange Online so I don't think what you want to do is possible.

[Supported email service configurations for server-side synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531050.aspx)